# Symfony2 collection and Doctrine2 ManyToMany - changes are saving but functions doesn't run

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

Something strange is happening with my SF2 application. I have 2 entities: [SettingsGroup](http://pastie.org/9616569) and [SettingValue](http://pastie.org/9616570).

I've created a form for SettingsGroup - [SettingsGroupEditType](http://pastie.org/9616572), **and when I'm saving the SettingsGroup entity neither of the functions addSetting or removeSetting is being called**, so the group is not being set.

Using Symfony2 v2.5.5 and Doctrine2 v2.3

Comment: show us 'admin_settings_edit' form

Comment: @BartłomiejWach http://pastie.org/9616636

Comment: You should try using the `by_reference` option in your settings `collection`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

Comment: @kix nope, still nothing

Comment: Could we see your Controller and View code?

Comment: @frumious Changes are saving, i have new entities SettingsValue and in join table, problem is that addSetting,removeSetting or setSettings doesn't run. Controller action (http://pastie.org/9617028) view(http://pastie.org/9617035). To handle collections I'm using mopa bootstrap bundle.

Comment: Could you post a dump of your entity (`$settingsForm->getData()`) just before saving it in your controller?

Comment: @FyodorX, easily. After saving http://pastie.org/9618285 and before http://pastie.org/9618303

Comment: I've been looking at this, and am stuck.  It doesn't make sense to me that (as we can see from the dump before persisting) the SettingsGroup does have the SettingValue objects, but the addSetting method can't be being called because it would have hit a `die`.  I've looked in the Symfony code that synchronises model and form data, and the only way it handles collections is to find and use the appropriate `addXXX` method, so it's a mystery.

Comment: My next steps would be to a) clear the cache (manually if necessary, I've had my cache get "locked" in such a way that `cache:clear` does nothing in the past), and b) run a debug session to trace execution into the Symfony code, the relevant bits are in `Form->submit()`, `PropertyPathMapper->mapFormsToData()`, `PropertyAccessor`.

Comment: @frumious I've cleared cache a few times, changed sf and doctrine versions. And I think I've found answer, https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/EventListener/MergeCollectionListener.php#L113-L121

Comment: Hmm. What makes you think it's that?  Because it modifies an array without calling methods?  Is it used in your specific case?

Comment: Possible stupid question: you did set `by-reference` to `false` (not `true`...) when you tried it out, didn't you?

Comment: @frumious Yes I think it modifying it like array, without setters and yes I've tried false\true in by-reference